# performSelectorWithDelay in serialQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've a serial queue and I use that queue to call a `performSelectorWithDelay` like below

`dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^(void) {
           [self performSelector:@selector(fetchConfigFromNetwork) withObject:nil afterDelay:rootConfig.waitTime];
       });`

However, the method `fetchConfigFromNetwork` never gets called. However, if instead of `serialQueue`, I use `mainQueue` - it starts working.

Cannot understand what's happening here and how to fix it?

Comment: Instead of using `performSelector...` with `dispatch_async`, just use `dispatch_after` and a normal method call inside.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation why your code doesn't work is in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416176-performselector?language=occ

> This method registers with the runloop of its current context, and
>   depends on that runloop being run on a regular basis to perform
>   correctly. One common context where you might call this method and end
>   up registering with a runloop that is not automatically run on a
>   regular basis is when being invoked by a dispatch queue. If you need
>   this type of functionality when running on a dispatch queue, you
>   should use dispatch_after and related methods to get the behavior you
>   want.

I'm assuming you want that method to be called on the serial queue with a delay. The most straight forward (and recommended way) is to use `dispatch_after`:

```
__weak typeof(self) wself = self;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(rootConfig.waitTime * NSEC_PER_SEC)), serialQueue, ^{
    [wself fetchConfigFromNetwork];
});
```

Comment: This is exactly how I've modified my code - but with this approach, I cannot do `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget`. Do you know, how can we solve that?

Comment: @prabodhprakash Have external state for whether the scheduled block should actually do work or not.

Comment: what @bbum said. Add a boolean that you check inside the block.

Answer (score 0):

> > This method sets up a timer to perform the aSelector message on the current thread’s run loop. The timer is configured to run in the default mode (NSDefaultRunLoopMode). When the timer fires, the thread attempts to dequeue the message from the run loop and perform the selector. It succeeds if the run loop is running and in the default mode; otherwise, the timer waits until the run loop is in the default mode.

This is the discussion about the method `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, I think the `block` of `dispatch_async` will execute on a new thread (not main thread), but you would not know which thread it is, so you can not new a runloop and open it and assign it to this thread. because the runloop of thread is close in default except the main thread, the timer will wait forever.

On my opinion, you should use `NSThread` instead of `dispatch_async`, and create a runloop for the thread that you use, then specified the mode of runloop with NSDefaultRunLoopMode, if you actually want to `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget`, otherwise use `dispatch_after` instead of `performSelector`.

That's my understanding. I can't promise it is right.